# Controle de janelas de navegador com Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou automatizando uma operação em um determinado site e em um dado momento eu preciso fazer um download, eu consigo autorizar o download clicando no link mas depois disso eu perco o controle, pois é aberta uma janela do Firefox perguntando se quero Abrir ou salvar o arquivo, como posso automatizar essa operação? Com o Selenium ou com o própio C#?

Comment: Os navegadores hoje suportam o download sem perguntar pelo local de salvamento do arquivo. Acho que esta é a solução mais simples para estes casos, se for uma opção válida para você :). Chrome e Firefox comportam-se assim por padrão nas versões recentes.

Comment: mas no formato específico que será baixado o firefox n permite marcar a opçao salvar sempre

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a ferramenta AutoIT.

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Normalmente usa-se em conjunto com automatizadores em outra linguagem para fazer funções dentro do sistema, onda a ferramenta não alcança (no seu caso, o Selenium). Eu já utilizei os dois em conjunto em um projeto para ele salvar automático um download no IE9. E aí eu nem precisei saber da linguagem porque encontrei na internet o cod. fonte do que eu queria. Apenas baixei, compilei, converti pra executável e quando eu precisava eu chama o executável.
Abraços.